# Jenkins: Where to add steps to create a dynamic view?

Tags: view, jenkins, syntax-error, clearcase

I am getting the below error, while building a job in Jenkins. The error occurs while starting a view. So I know I need to create that view before starting it so that it wont error out.

But my query is where in Jenkins should I add these step to create a dynamic view even before starting it?

```
Building remotely on my_machine in workspace c:/hw/workspace/my_project_13.6
[my_project_13.6] $ cleartool startview username_my_machine_my_project_13.6
cleartool: Error: View tag not found: "username_my_machine_my_project_13.6".
FATAL: Base ClearCase failed. exit code=1
java.io.IOException: cleartool did not return the expected exit code. Command line="startview username_my_machine_my_project_13.6", actual exit code=1
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.HudsonClearToolLauncher.run(HudsonClearToolLauncher.java:120)
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.ClearToolExec.startView(ClearToolExec.java:913)
    at hudson.plugins.clearcase.action.BaseDynamicCheckoutAction.startView(BaseDynamicCheckoutAction.java:115)
```

Answer (score 0):

At what step is that `cleartool startview` been called. If that's a build task then add a command to create the dynamic view before the script is called.

Or you can try to create dependant jobs in jenkins and run your current jobs only once the 'create view' job is complete(I know it would be a small job, but this is just to fix the issue). To understand the error, we would need more info .